# How to rename dart file in VSCode?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Working with dart/flutter in VSCode (1.38.1). I want to rename a class, so want to rename its dart file. I right-click on the filename in VSCode and rename the dart file. I then change all its imports to reflect the name, but when I run Debug, I get the error

```
path\old_name.dart were declared as an inputs, but did not exist. Check the definition of target:kernel_snapshot for errors
```

What more does one have to do to rename a file in VSCode/dart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your project directory, type in the terminal

```sh
flutter clean
```

Then run again

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my OP that I tried flutter clean and it didn't work for me. Will modify now.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys `flutter clean` command essentially delete that folder. Did you write a flutter app or an isolated package? If you develop flutter package, and you run the app in the `example/` subfolder, then you have to go to the examples folder (`cd examples`) before you run that command

Answer (score 10):

Just delete .dart_tool folder, and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

To rename you class just put the cursor on then class name and press F2. Then type the new name and it would be done.